# C# I want to sort 2D array, but my code only rewrites it

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, url-rewriting, 2d

I did not find this question, so i Would like to ask. I am sorting 2D array using this code

```
for (long j = 0; j < Text.Length; j++) 
            {
                if (AbsMinDis[i] < AbsMinDis[PosMin])
                {
                    CurXpos = XPos[i];
                    CurYpos = YPos[i];
                    string swap = Word[PosMin, j];
                    Word[PosMin, j] = Word[i, j];
                    Word[i, j] = swap;
                    PosMin = i;
                }
            }
```

then, i am writing it like that:

```
for (long i = 0; i < Text.Length; i++)
        {
            FileSorted.Write(Word[i, 0]);
            for (byte k = 1; k < 8; k++)
            {
                FileSorted.Write(" {0}", Word[i, k]);
            }
            FileSorted.WriteLine();
        }
        FileSorted.Close();
```

what it does is that it rewrite code in exact order as original. I am using this code to find the closest distance between elements `AbsMinDis` and then sort them and write into file.
Thank you for your help

Variables

```
 StreamWriter FileSorted = new StreamWriter("C://Users//Tomas//Desktop//Bakalárka//Fiel test//Fiel test//tmp//Data.txt");
        long PosMin = 0; //position of line with minimum
        for (long i = 0; i < Text.Length; i++) // search for minimal distance
        {
            double X1 = Math.Round(double.Parse(Word[i, 1], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 3); // X start possition to double
            double Y1 = Math.Round(double.Parse(Word[i, 2], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 3); //Y , etc.
            double X2 = Math.Round(double.Parse(Word[i, 3], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 3);
            double Y2 = Math.Round(double.Parse(Word[i, 4], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 3);
            double[] XPos = new double[Text.Length]; // array of smallest distances for each line
            double[] YPos = new double[Text.Length];
            double MinDis1 = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(X1 - CurXpos, 2) + Math.Pow(Y1 - CurXpos, 2)); //calculation of the smallest distances
            double MinDis2 = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(X2 - CurXpos, 2) + Math.Pow(Y2 - CurYpos, 2)); //calculate if end points are closer        
            double[] AbsMinDis = new double[Text.Length]; // line containing distance data of each line
            if (MinDis1 < MinDis2) // if distance of starting coordinate is smaller than ending, save
```

Comment: Where is `i`defined/updated in the first loop?

Comment: `i` is originally in for loop that is not mentioned here, after that loop ends, then start this new loop. because of code length i did not wrote it all

Comment: Can you please post your variables definition?

Comment: because of length i have edited my post

Comment: What about `Word`?

Comment: Well data file to sort consist of words (1st one is name of elements, all others are measurements and coordinates) so I have decided to call this array Word